# GlassFish 4 deserialization throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, serialization, glassfish, deserialization

I have classes with transient variables, inner classes and enums like:

```
public class TestClass {
  enum MyEnum { ABC, DEF }
  MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.ABC;
  transient String str = "Some Text";
  ... }
```

Invoking a remote method in GlassFish 4 or getting this class as the response

```
System.out.println( "myEnum=" + testClass.myEnum );
```

will print `null`

I would expect, that the deserialization creates a new instance of this class (e.g. invoking newInstance()). The same problem exists with inner classes and transient variables which **should be** initialized during instantiation.

On the other hand, its hard to believe that I'm the first one to find this out. Am I thinking in the wrong direction here?

Comment: What is the sense of marking a String transient?

Comment: Because it makes no sense to persist it or send it remotely. Imagine a very long text or some inner classes like enums instead.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is by design.

The alternative - calling a no-argument constructor corresponding to the transient field - could have unwanted side effects.

Comment: You say its by design. Where do I find the specification? What 'unwanted' side effects could there be?

Comment: What happens, for example, if the constructor throws an exception? Simply setting to `null` is *far* more sensible. I'll have a look at the JLS later.

Comment: Interesting point. Anyway this behavior will prevent internal enums and classes. This requires a different programming model in some areas.